# How to move table row to other amps in Teradata?

Tags: database, teradata

Let`s say there are clique 1(contains 4 nodes) and clique 2 (contains 2 nodes).
and the table rows are being distributed across clique 1 and clique 2 nodes amps.
When clique 2 failed, we lost our access to some of important tables.
As one of our options, we want to transfer these important tables to clique 1 nodes (amps) only.
How do you do this? I looked into some manuals and looks like sparse maps can be used but I am having trouble determining the amp number of those nodes that are in clique1.
And the table I am referring to has million of rows, I am afraid it will cause amp skew.
Does anyone have alternative solution for this? Will appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

Comment: When a clique fails there's no more Teradata system. If you just lost some tables they were not Fallback protected. Simply switch on Fallback for important tables.

Comment: Yes, tables were not Fallback protected. I`m sorry for not being clear, to correct my statement, one of the nodes of clique 2 failed and we lost access to some of the tables. I guess having Fallback is our only option. Thanks for your comment @dnoeth!